# highlight search word using jquery in MVC

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net-mvc, search, highlight

I have MVC controller that returns a list containing a search string.

```
 public ActionResult GetList(string searchString)
    {
        ViewData["searchString"] = searchString; 
        if (String.IsNullOrEmpty(searchString))
          {
            var persons = db.Persons.ToList(); 
            return View(persons);
          } 
        else{
            var persons = db.Persons.Where(p=> p.Title.Contains(searchString)).ToList(); 
            return View(persons);
             }
     }
```

In the view the list is displayed in a table.  I want to highlight the searchString (or at most the td that contains the searchString). The following is my jquery where I attempted to achieve this.  I have tried putting this bit of code in a separate .js script or in the view itself and I have also tried to change the code in several ways but it wouldn't work.  It appears like the searchString remains null even if the content of my ViewData has changed.

```
    $(document).ready(function () {

     var textToHighligt = @ViewData["searchString"];
     $("#simpleSearchButton").click(function () {
     $("td:contains(textToHighligt)").css("background-color", "yellow"); 
       });
       });
```

Comment: How you are calling the GetList method is it AJAX call or simple post ?

Comment: I have not used AJAX. @Devesh

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you can do otherwise if it is not happening in the javascript file , create a hidden field and populate the value from the ViewBag

```
       @Html.Hidden("hiddensearchString", (string)ViewBag.searchString)
```

For the ViewData

```
      @Html.Hidden("FirstName", ViewData["searchString"])
```

and then the javascript read the value like this

```
       var searchString = $("#hiddensearchString").val();
```

In you code you can also try this using of the single quote.

```
        var textToHighligt = '@ViewData["searchString"]';
```

Comment: Thank you.  It worked when I saved the viewBag in the Hidden field.

Answer (score 1):

I think this:

```
var textToHighligt = @ViewData["searchString"];
$("td:contains(textToHighligt)").css("background-color", "yellow");
```

should be concatenated:

```
var textToHighligt = '@ViewData["searchString"]'; //<---put in quotes
$("td:contains("+textToHighligt+")").css("background-color", "yellow");
```

Comment: One problem is that when I add the declaration                                        var myText= @ViewData["searchString"], the jquery stops to function even for some basic command like alert("abc").  I have tried definining it in the script tag but above (document).ready and wouldn't work either

Comment: @Tibuka04 - is your JS in the view or a standalone file?

Comment: @Tommy As I said I tried both ways.  Right now, I am using it in a stand alone file called highlighter.js  and I have of course in the view the script tags.                                                                                          <script src="~/Scripts/jquery-1.10.2.js"></script>
    <script src="~/Scripts/highlighter.js"></script>

Comment: @Tibuka04 -  You cannot use razor syntax in a standalone file.  You have to find a way to pass that data from razor into your javascript function (either as a parameter or set a global JS variable in your view)

Comment: @Tommy In that case it should have worked when I have the JS in the view.  One problem I see(by using the alert function) is that the js is executed right after the click before the new list is received and displayed in the view.  Thus it is not executed on the page that displays the results with the search string.

Comment: @Tibuka04 - you are not showing going and getting a list, your code makes it seem like the list is there when the page loads.  I feel you need to restructure your question a bit more.  Is this list part of the view when you first load the page? are you getting it via ajax?  These are important things to know when asking a question on SO.

Comment: @Tommy when the page loads, it loads a list of all Persons because the searchString passed is null/empty.  There is a form on the page that consists of a text box and submit button.  One writes the searchString and now it loads with a new list with persons containing only whose Title contains the searchString.  The highlight is needed here.  As I said, I am not using Ajax and js is not used in anyway to retrive a list.